# static macro-based State Machine implementation

Tags: beginner, rust, state-machine

While learning Rust for the past couple of weeks, I set out to use the type-system to build a static State Machine implementation in Rust.

The goals:

- program in idiomatic Rust
- no runtime overhead
- use traits for flexibility
- optionally use macro's for ease of use
- keep it simple

I believe I managed to achieve all, except for maybe the third point. The end-result is a macro that generates a new struct for each state machine, so there's no overarching trait to easily generate your own state machine without the included macro.

I'm curious:

- If I approached this in the right way
- What I could have done differently
- If I wanted to rely more heavily on the trait system (while keeping the zero-runtime cost) how I would go about doing that

My next extension to this would be to implement some kind of enum-based type on top of this, to make it easy to match against the current state, as right now that's not yet possible.

Code can be viewed [on GitHub](https://github.com/rusty-rockets/sm/blob/e9ef152c8d03a48ef5c31a30bcb4f8e364b6ad37/src/lib.rs#L495-L607), or below:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! sm {
    (
        $($name:ident {
            States { $($state:ident),+ $(,)* }

            $($event:ident {
                $($($from:ident),+ => $to:ident)+
            })*
        })+
    ) => {
        use $crate::{AsEnum, Machine as M, Transition};

        $(
            #[allow(non_snake_case)]
            pub mod $name {
                use $crate::{AsEnum, Event, Machine as M, State, Transition};

                #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
                pub struct Machine<S: State>(pub S);

                impl<S> M for Machine<S> where S: State {
                    type State = S;

                    fn state(&self) -> S {
                        self.0.clone()
                    }
                }

                impl<S> Machine<S> where S: State {
                    pub fn new(state: S) -> Self {
                        Machine(state)
                    }
                }

                $(
                    #[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, Debug)]
                    pub struct $state;
                    impl State for $state {}

                    impl PartialEq<$state> for $state {
                        fn eq(&self, _: & $state) -> bool {
                            true
                        }
                    }
                )*

                #[derive(Debug)]
                pub enum States {
                    $($state(Machine<$state>)),*
                }

                $(
                    impl AsEnum<$state> for Machine<$state> {
                        type Enum = States;

                        fn as_enum(self) -> Self::Enum {
                            States::$state(self)
                        }
                    }
                )*

                sm!{@recurse ($($state),*), ()}

                $(
                    #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
                    pub struct $event;
                    impl Event for $event {}

                    $(
                        $(
                            impl Transition<Machine<$to>, $event> for Machine<$from> {
                                fn transition(self, _: $event) -> Machine<$to> {
                                    Machine::new($to)
                                }
                            }
                        )*
                    )*
                )*
            }
        )*
    };

    (@recurse ($state:ident, $($other:ident),+), ($($old:ident),*)) => {
        $(
            impl PartialEq<$other> for $state {
                fn eq(&self, _: & $other) -> bool {
                    false
                }
            }
        )*

        $(
            impl PartialEq<$old> for $state {
                fn eq(&self, _: & $old) -> bool {
                    false
                }
            }
        )*

        sm!{@recurse ($($other),*), ($($old,)* $state)}
    };

    (@recurse ($state:ident), ($($old:ident),*)) => {
        $(
            impl PartialEq<$old> for $state {
                fn eq(&self, _: & $old) -> bool {
                    false
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}
```

Comment: I just realised that while all my tests are green, that's because they only test the "happy path". You can't actually do any conditional expression on the current `state`, since its type differs (by design) from any of the other states, and so a derived `PartialEq` won't work. I guess the solution(?) to this is to somehow recurse over all _other_ states for each state, and generate a `PartialEq<OtherState>` implementation for each, which returns `false`. I do feel like this is where I'm probably lacking insights into the proper use of generics to not have to do this recursion for every state.

Comment: I've since solved the above mentioned problem and updated both the URL and the inline code example. Feel free to leave me any feedback!

Comment: I've updated the code again to the latest iteration, in case anyone is interested in giving it a review. I'm also in the process of rewriting it to use procedural macros, but that's quite a change in code, so perhaps a new review would be best, instead of updating this again. Still very much interested in learning from anyone that has some interesting insights to share!

Comment: Why use macros? State machines can be implemented in Rust with the type system alone. This uses the concept of typestates and is likely much easier to reason about. https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/static-guarantees/state-machines.html

Comment: @RubberDuck You are right. That's what I wrote in the introduction: "I set out to use the type-system to build a static State Machine implementation in Rust". Using macros does not mean _not_ using the type-system, it's meant to abstract away boilerplate code. See the difference between https://github.com/rustic-games/sm/tree/master/examples/turnstile-manual and https://github.com/rustic-games/sm/tree/master/examples/turnstile-macro (same types and outcome, one using the macro, and one using manual configuration). I guess it's a personal preference which approach you prefer.

Comment: I see now. Maybe some examples of using the generated implementations would help. I guess you could consider that a review in and of itself. The macros do reduce duplication and *theoretically* maintenance cost, but it’s **much** harder to reason about, which increases the maintenance cost. It’s probably a wash at the end of the day.